# How to transfer Nifti file into .mat Matlab file?

Tags: matlab, file-conversion, mat-file, nifti

I have a Nifti file, the size of which is 62*62*38. How can I  transfer the Nifti file to .mat Matlab file?

Comment: Never used Nifti in my life, but google recommends http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image

Comment: @MikhailGenkin, why you say "never used Nifti in my life", what are you using in your life now?

Comment: @Angelbaby Is that rhetorical question? Did I say something wrong? Yes, I am not a native speaker and could sometimes speak unclearly.

Comment: @MikhailGenkin,  I understand what you are trying to express.  I am just curious why nifti is not popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d) can read NIFTI as well as many other medical image file types into MATLAB arrays, which you can then save as .mat files.

Comment: The "volume" class the toolbox generate  is "single" , not "double" class. How to transfer to "double" class??

Comment: @Angelababy If you need to convert the image to double-precision after reading it, you can use `im = double(im);`.

Answer (score 2):

Most medical imaging data can be manipulated effectively using some kind of toolbox, such as SPM. However, if you need to gain access to the raw matrix I've always used NIfTI tools from the Mathworks file exchange site ([here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image)).

There are two functions that are relevant here: `load_nii` and `load_untouched_nii`. The first function `load_nii` takes care of situations where the header in the NiFTI contains transformations that haven't been applied to the underlying data matrix. If you know that no such transformations exist, you can use `load_untouched_nii` to avoid the reslicing being done. Both functions return a structure, and the data matrix is located in the `img` field of the returned structure.

Comment: the "img" field generated by "load_untouch_nii() " is int16. How can I change it to "double" class

Comment: @Angelababy Don't have access to Matlab right now but shouldn't a call to  [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) solve that?

Comment: I already know double(im) solve the problem. Your answer is also good. I do not know how to vote two persons' answer as right answers. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the difference between `load_nii` and `load_untouch_nii` cleared up some confusion I was having.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeSurfer](http://freesurfer.net/) has a MATLAB function called "MRIread". It can read NIFTI (.nii, .nii.gz) files into a MATLAB structure, which can then be saved to a MAT file if so desired.

Comment: it is installed on Linux System. I use windows(no virtualBox). I am not familiar with Linux.